# Image ALT showing in source but not showing in browser element inspector

Tags: angular, alt

I've been puzzled by the fact I have the same code structure for two different Angular apps whereby a link has inside an image like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['myUrl/', resourceUri()]">
    <img class="transition" 
         [src]="myObject.mainImageUrl"
         [alt]="createAlt()">
</a>
```

If I view the source of the page, the ALT is correctly there however when I'm inspecting the image element, in Firefox, Chrome or Safari, I can't see the alt attribute being populated. Does anyone know why could that be?

What is even more strange is that I have seen this working for one angular app and not working for a different app; same code, different object structure, but the principal is the same. The Angular version is different 7.1.4 vs 7.2.1 but I really doubt that's the problem. I have cleared caches, hard refreshed or even made other changes to the site which appeared as expected.

Comment: What does `createAlt` do or return?

Comment: It does return the alt string: public createAlt = (): string => {
        return `some alt - ${this.myObject.title}`;
    }

Comment: I think we'll need more information to help debug this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyh3mg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: OK - small detail...when I do ng serve on my local I can see the ALT correctly populated. However because I'm doing SSR, when I deploy to the server - and I make sure it's the latest image - the code changes are in there (I can see them in view source) however the actual UI does not reflect that change if that makes sense

Comment: It turned out to be a docker configuration issue. There was a volume mounted on the actual website container which wasn't renewed on version update therefore the old code was showing up! Thanks for the help!